# Tool to organize and arrange various monitoring pages?

Tags: mac-osx, monitoring, nagios

we recently added a MacPro with eight (yes 8) monitors on it.  We have various tools for monitoring our website (Chartbeat, Nagios, internal statistics, Jenkins, Smartfox, etc.) and they are currently free-flowing in various browser windows on the various screens.

I'd like a better way to organize them into a more fixed system so 
(a) we can't just accidentally close out of a window
(b) some automatically refresh (currently done through browser plugins)
etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want a [tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). The description is complicated, but the idea is simple: A tiling WM arranges windows so that there's no overlap. There's a question on [tiling WMs for OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/162849/tiling-window-manager-for-mac-os-x) at SuperUser, I'd use one of their recommendations to tile the browser windows across the 8 screens.

If your tools are internal, you should be able to modify the monitoring page to [reload automatically](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479551/Reloading-The-Page.htm#itself).

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to shoehorn a solution for a problem you shouldn't have: Your monitoring system should not rely on having web pages open (and by extension, on people looking at them).  What happens when your monitoring person has to go take a leak, slips on a puddle in the rest room, cracks their head on the side of the toilet and drowns? ***It Could Happen!***

---

That said, a tiling window manager and some creative use of [AppleScript](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptX/AppleScriptX.html) can probably do what you want.  Implementation of the solution is left as an exercise for the reader (because without being inside your environment we can't really determine what you need to do).

Answer (score 2):

I use a firefox-plugin called "Tile Tabs" where you can tile your browser screen and load different monitoring-sites. You can also save the current tiles and load them again. So maybe you stretch your firefox across multiple monitors and just divide the content. For reloading i use the "ReloadEvery" plugin, where i can set the reload time in the context-menu of every tile if i need to. Its also a good solution for full-hd-tv screens to show a summary of your monitoring.

Comment: Linking these suggested plugins would be a good improvement to this already-helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Nagios in your environment you're already there. Nagios can be set up to take in the feeds from all the various monitors you have in place and present a single combined view of everything. I've been a Nagios consultant for a number of years now. Send me a private message if you'd like to discuss this further.